# How to set the Cap'n Proto RPC message traversal limit?

Tags: rust, rpc, capnproto

I need to send an RPC with the Rust Cap'n Proto API that exceeds the default message traversal limit. When I try to send the message, I get the following error:

```
remote exception: <class \'capnp.lib.capnp.KjException
\'>:capnp/arena.c++:130: failed: Exceeded message traversal limit.
See capnp::ReaderOptions.
```

If I were reading a message using [`capnp::serialize::read_message`](https://docs.capnproto-rust.org/capnp/serialize/fn.read_message.html), I could provide a [`ReaderOptions`](https://docs.capnproto-rust.org/capnp/message/struct.ReaderOptions.html) struct specifying a new traversal limit.

However, I am making and sending a request like in the [calculator example](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto-rust/blob/master/capnp-rpc/examples/calculator/client.rs#L125) instead of reading a message directly. How can I set the traversal limit for my request message?

Comment: is it possible to adapt the answer you accepted when using pythong and captain proto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67374563/how-to-read-a-captain-proto-message-bin-file-without-prematures-eofs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it when you construct the [`VatNetwork`](https://docs.capnproto-rust.org/capnp_rpc/twoparty/struct.VatNetwork.html):

```
pub fn new<U>(
    input_stream: T,
    output_stream: U,
    side: Side,
    receive_options: ReaderOptions,
) -> VatNetwork<T>
where
    U: Write + 'static,
```

https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto-rust/issues/124#issuecomment-468877758

Comment: is it possible to adapt your answer when using pythong and captain proto? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67374563/how-to-read-a-captain-proto-message-bin-file-without-prematures-eofs